# If $M = IM$ and $M$ finitely generated, then $M_m = 0$ for all $I \subseteq m$, $m$ maximal.

Tags: commutative-algebra

The question is as follows: let $M$ be an $R$-module, $I$ an $R$-ideal, and we want to show that if $M = IM$ and $M$ is finitely generated, then $M_m = 0$ for all maximal ideals containing $I$. By first hunch is to use Nakayama's Lemma since $M$ is finitely generated, but I have no idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: If $M=IM$ then $M=\mathfrak {m}M$ if $I\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

You could show directly (using the Cayley-Hamilton determinant trick) that there exists $i \in I$ so that $(1+i) \cdot M=0$. That would imply the claim right away. Or you can use Nakayama for $m_m \cdot M_m = M_m$

Comment: Oh, so for the second one we have $m_m \cdot M_m = M_m$ and $m_m$ is the Jacobson radical, so $M_m = 0$?

Comment: @User203940: yes, the ring is local, so the maximal ideal is the Jacobson

Comment: That was easier than expected. Thank you!